# magento from linux to windows cannot login - invalid formkey

Tags: magento

I transferred my magento installation on ubuntu with files and mysql db dump to my development machine on Windows 10 with XAMPP installed.

I can up the frontend, but I cannot login my admin backend.

I am sure the password and user name are exactly as my installation on ubuntu, why happened? It just stay on the login form and saying all the time invalid formkey, I viewed the source formkey value just generated there.

There mentioned issue with charset, tried no help.

There is no any error logged in var/report and XAMPP apache errorlog, access_log to /index.php/admin is 200, looks good.

will you have any idea? thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you accessing the admin? Like this: http://localhost/admin? If so try http://127.0.0.1/admin

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Possible causes include

- Incorrect permissions on var/session, preventing session files from
  being saved
- Incorrect configuration of database/redis/other session storage,
  preventing saving of session values
- A module is instantiating sessions to early, preventing the correct
  session names from being set
- The cookie domain in System -> Configuration -> Web -> Session Cookie
  Management doesn't match the actual site domain.
- You're using the localhost as your server domain, and using a version
  of webkit that has trouble/bugs setting cookies for localhost in some
  situations.

Easier is just to use the IP-address 127.0.0.1 to access Magento.

Answer (score 0):

Open magento database and run below query.

```
update `core_config_data` set `value`='/' where `path`='web/cookie/cookie_path';
update `core_config_data` set `value`='[magentohost]' where `path`='web/cookie/cookie_domain';
```

If you have setup multiple store with subdomains, add Cookie Domain: **.magentohost.com**
Add a dot “.” follwed by Magento URL.

source : [CodePetals](http://www.codepetals.com/magento-unable-to-login-to-admin-after-install/)